# How to solve black screen on VM linux on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, chrome-remote-desktop

I have a VM on GCP that running linux Debian, when I try to use Chrome Remote Desktop this VM do not open a graphic interface.

I did the steps to configure my environment, but when I open my VM only a black screen is showned.

See the image:

[black screnn image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idIcl.png)

I did a search on the internet but no sucess, yet.

Comment: Your query is not very clear. Have you followed installing the pre-req packages post deployment via SSH? What steps have you taken to configure the environment? You might want to refer this guide - https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine. Please make sure to explain steps taken.

Comment: Hi @jningthou, thanks a lot for this link. I did the steps that are in this tutorial, but it always showed the black screen only. But this time the graphical interface went up. To thank!

Comment: Great, it resolved the issue. Would be great if you could share the steps to repro the issue and what steps you took to resolve it so it helps other folks facing similar issues in future. Cheers!